# How to install MintTools in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, mint

Is there a clean way to install some of the [MintTools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_mint#Software_developed_by_Linux_Mint) in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04? I'm interested in the Software Manager (mintInstall); Update Manager (mintUpdate); Backup tool (mintBackup); and Upload Manager (mintUpload).

Alternatively, if these were derived/inspired by other software with similar Quality of Life features (available in Ubuntu), that would be welcome too. I realized that mintBackup may have drawn some inspiration from Aptik, which offers the option of backing up installed applications (while Deja Dup is not as versatile, backing up all files).

I'm running Mint on an secondary computer, and I found the Software Manager offered more insight into the quality of apps (when searching for an app, you get average rating AND # of ratings; there are useful screen shots when you click on a result); the Update Manager notifies you which updates can break the system; the Backup Manager lets me backup installed apps (without having to backup the files themselves); etc.

However, I much prefer Gnome or Unity, over Mint's DEs.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you already installed that tools and have a good experience with them ;-) So is it a pure Mint promotion?

Comment: @Pilot6 :  LOL, no: I'm running Mint on a different computer, and thought these were great features. But I much prefer Gnome/Unity over Mint's DEs. (And I haven't had any responses to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347014/how-to-install-gnome-3-in-linux-mint-18-1-serena). Anyway, clarified in question =).